# How can we randomly change image when we refresh the page every time in PHP

Tags: php

How can we randomly change image when we refresh the page every time in PHP

Answer (score 8):

Load the possible image extensions into an array. Use rand() to generate a random integer within range of the length of this array, and display it in your HTML.

```
$images = array('img1.png', 'img2.png');
$rand = array_rand($input, 1); // number of random keys to generate
echo "<img src=\"".$images[$rand[0]]."\" alt=\"this image\">";
```

Comment: Just make  `alt` an empty value... if the `alt` text cannot entirely replace the image in its context, it should be empty.

Comment: Oh and also have a look at the http://www.php.net/array_rand function... `$images[array_rand($images)];` It's especially useful when you want several random entries. `$keys = array_rand($images, 3);`

Comment: I agree with Blixt. Unless your filenames are sensible enough that you could drop them in the alt text instead.

Comment: I agree with you that array_rand would be a good improvement. As for the alt text I think you're over analyzing it, of course it can be changed to anything.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an array of image names.
2. Generate a random number between 0 and the length of the array.
3. Generate an `<img>` tag using the image name corresponding to that random number.